# How to compare strings in Vb.Net from 2 different text boxes?

Tags: vb.net

Im making a program where I want to be able to paste in my email list, then search through the list and compare them to a list of strings in another textbox, and if any of it matches, then the email address gets moved to a third textbox.

For example, if I wanted to filter all the gmails and hotmails, I would enter them in the box, paste the emails in the other box and click go.

But it doesn't seem to work properly, with only a few entries it seems to work fine, but if i paste more than a few emails it only seems to detect gmails(or whatever the first entry i have in the compare textbox). 
I hope this makes sense I can't figure out why it wont work. 
Here is my code

```
    Dim compare As String
    Dim comparear() As String
    Dim list As String
    Dim listar() As String

    compare = txtcompare.Text
    comparear = compare.Split(vbNewLine)
    list = txtlist.Text
    listar = list.Split(vbNewLine)
    For i = 0 To comparear.Length - 1
        For p = 0 To listar.Length - 1
            If listar(p).Contains(comparear(i)) Then
                txtresult.Text = txtresult.Text & listar(p) 
            Else
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Hey Aethlen thanks for the quick answer, but it didnt work :(, comparear may only have 10 lines in it, whereas listAr might have 100 so i need both loops i think

Comment: I think I misunderstand your question, correct me if I am wrong, you want to check if comparear() items exists in listAr() items?

Comment: Correct, I would like to check if comparear exists in each one of listAr() items. And if it does exist, I would like that item in ListAr() to be sent over the the txtresults textbox.  Basically in comparear I have written stuff like "gmail, hotmail" and would like it to go through the ListAr() and copy any matching gmail or hotmails, Sorry im not great at explaining :/ Thanks for your response!

Comment: So you're not searching for exact matches rather than text containing "gmail", "hotmail" or anything based on your textbox.. try my new answer.

Comment: Hey, tried that code too, same thing happens, I get a list of all the gmails, but no hotmails, Or all the hotmails if its first in the comparear list :/ I really don't understand why its doing this.

Comment: try using a string first rather than the txtresult textbox. after you've passed those in a string, prompt the string with a messagebox. I wanna see what the messagebox says..

Comment: I forgot to say try separating the text in txtcompare.text with comma (,) then split it with that instead of vbNewLine. if you are using a multiline textbox, use "vbLf" instead

Comment: Omg your a genius! It works fine splitting by comma! Thank you soooo much

Comment: just mark my answer if your problem was solved :D

Comment: ...and I got nothing for all my efforts.. cruel world :(

Comment: Sorry Im just slow :P Haha you don't know how much I appreciate your help thank you :D

Comment: thanks! haha.. I'm just being emo today since windows update stopped me from working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
  comparear = compare.Split(vbNewLine)
  ...
  listar = list.Split(vbNewLine)
```

With this:

```
  comparear = compare.Split(",")
  ...
  listar = list.Split(",")
```

If you split the search criterias into commas(,)